# Setting up Git on AWS for Apache Derby

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, derby

I'm new to working in clouds and Git, so please bear with me and ELI5.

I am trying to set up Git to work on my AWS instance with Apache Derby installed. I'd like to be able to back up all my Apache Derby work (for which I use IJ to access and work on it) using Git, but so far all I've managed to do is to install Git on my AWS instance. I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. A couple of tutorials online and some answers here helped me get to this point, but I couldn't find anything specific about Apache Derby.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge all one can do is set up Git on AWS (as explained in various blogs and on this website) and whatever you do in Apache Derby, it will be recorded in a log on the AWS instance, which can then be committed to Git. Happy to be corrected if anyone else finds a better solution.